# Is it idiomatic to say "I never minded about..."?

Tags: expression-choice

For example: "I never minded about not getting paid for it". Does this sentence sound fine or should it be "I never cared about.."?

Comment: The second is better.  The first is not necessarily wrong.  And one suspects that you could do better.

Comment: "I never minded that..." is more common,  I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=never%20minded%20about%2Cnever%20cared%20that%2Cnever%20minded%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnever%20minded%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnever%20cared%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnever%20minded%20that%3B%2Cc0) shows that *never minded about* is not uncommon, but *never minded that* and *never cared that* are far more common. *never minded that* is the most common, and has practically always been so.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is fine and can be found as shown by this search at Google Books

["never minded about"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%22I%20never%20minded%20about%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22never%20minded%20about%22)
about 2,750 results

in writers from George Eliot to Joanna Trollope.

> [Middlemarch (Illustrated)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=wev7AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT713&dq=%22never%20minded%20about%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=joMeVbvzF8G1sAS6pYKoBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22never%20minded%20about%22&f=false): George Eliot
>
> ... Dodo **never minded about** precedence if she could have her own
>   way.